# PHP - Contact form sent message

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I found a great contact form over [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-php-contact-form.html/comment-page-3). How to show a "Successfully sent" message right under the contact from instead of using a redirect to an other page?

```
$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('9nLzAt2cQM2Zysm');


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show some examples of [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  Most people will not read through that tutorial to solve your problem for you.

Comment: echo 'You have Successfully sent your message';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form process code to this.

```
$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('9nLzAt2cQM2Zysm');

$successful = false;
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $successful = true;
   }
}
```

Where you want the message to show.

```
if($successful){
  echo "Successfully sent.";
}
```